# How Do I turn this into a dataframe I can work with in R

Tags: r

Hi so I tried downloading this file and I can not graph it in any shape or form

```
> tomatoes
             V1
1   yield,mulch
2     4547,bare
3     2512,bare
4     4840,bare
5  6749,compost
6  7616,compost
7  6256,compost
8   4689,ground
9         cover
10  3831,ground
11        cover
12  4269,ground
13        cover
14 4488,plastic
15 3764,plastic
16 2824,plastic
17   3695,straw
18   5901,straw
19   7106,straw
```

I have tried

> ggplot(tomatoes, aes(x=yield))+ geom_dotplot()+facet_grid(~mulch)
>   Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `mulch`.
>   * Plot is missing `mulch`
>   * Layer 1 is missing `mulch` 
>   How can I fix this

Comment: You need to split the values at the comma to obtain two separate columns, one with the numerical info, one with the factor levels. Try the function `str_extract` from `library(stringr)`. One more thing: why do some rows not contain any numbers but only the value `cover`?

Comment: For example, like this: `tomatoes <- data.frame(V1 = c("yield,mulch","4547,bare","2512,bare", "4840,bare"))
tomatoes$yield <- str_extract(tomatoes$V1, "\\d+")
tomatoes$mulch <- str_extract(tomatoes$V1, "[A-z]+")`

Comment: You need to clean up your data, which appears to be stored in a single column with the comma as the intended separator. The first row should contain values, but at present contains column names.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
tomatoes <- data.frame(V1 = c("yield,mulch","4547,bare","2512,bare", 
                              "4840,bare", "6749,compost","7616,compost"))
```

Split `V1`into two columns at the comma:

```
tomatoes$yield <- str_extract(tomatoes$V1, "\\d+")
tomatoes$mulch <- str_extract(tomatoes$V1, "[A-z]+")
```

Draw your plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tomatoes[-1,], aes(x=yield))+ geom_dotplot()+facet_grid(~mulch)
```

[image]